# get dynamic $_POST data into a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= ${"ConteggioColonneTabella".$NomeTabella}; $i++) {
    ${'record'.$i} = addslashes($_POST['record'].$i);
}
```

Look at

```
addslashes($_POST['record'].$i);
```

This isn't correct, i know, but I can't figure out what is the correct syntax for getting POST variables.

================= EDIT ==================

This works outside the loop

```
$i = 1;
${'record'.$i} = addslashes($_POST[record.$i])
```

getting only one result

this doens't work inside the loop, getting no results

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    ${'record'.$i} = addslashes($_POST['record'].$i);
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['record' . $i]`

Comment: `$_POST . $i` would produce "valuefromfield**42**"

Comment: This works OUTSIDE the for loop 

${'record'.$i} = addslashes($_POST[record.$i]);

INSIDE no works

Comment: outside the loop you write `addslashes($_POST[record.$i])`, inside `addslashes($_POST[record'].$i)` it's not the same.